# How use correctly a condition with dates in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.usu_id,
    t2.usu_nombre,
    t2.usu_apellido
FROM
    act_regisdiario t1
INNER JOIN
    act_usuario t2
ON
    (t2.usu_id = t1.usu_id)
WHERE
     t1.rdi_fechacti != '2016-06-02 00:00:00' 
 AND t2.usu_admin = 0
GROUP BY 
    t2.usu_id
```

and the query work with 2 tables:

act_regisdiario:

[image]

and act_usuarios:

[image]

So i want yo select the users that have a different `rdi_fechacti`. And in this case is : 2016-06-02 00:00:00

But this show me all `usu_nombre` , but only `Jean` have 2016-06-02 00:00:00

I need only show `Jean`.

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

All the users have at least one row that meets your condition.

Instead use `not exists`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM act_usuario u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM act_regisdiario r
                  WHERE u.usu_id = r.usu_id AND
                        r.rdi_fechacti = '2016-06-02 00:00:00'
                 )
      u.usu_admin = 0;
```

Notice that you don't need aggregation for this either.

Answer (score 0):

You query was asking for any that had any without that datetime, this attempts to JOIN with records with that datetime and only accepts ones that "failed":

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t2.usu_id,
t2.usu_nombre,
t2.usu_apellido
FROM act_usuario t2
LEFT JOIN act_regisdiario t1
ON (t2.usu_id = t1.usu_id AND t1.rdi_fechacti = '2016-06-02 00:00:00')
WHERE t1.rdi_fechacti IS NULL and t2.usu_admin = 0
ORDER BY t2.usu_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `WHERE` clause to this:

```
WHERE t1.rdi_fechacti < '2016-06-02 00:00:00' OR t1.rdi_fechacti > '2016-06-02 23:59:59'
    and t2.usu_admin = 0
```

This says to exclude anything with a `t1.rdi_fechacti == '2016-06-02 00:00:00'` and it doesn't require a huge change to your starting code. You should be able to just update the date portion of the `DATETIME` to search for any others that may fit in your window of exclusion.

I hope this helps.

-C§